# Need to have nested ng content using angular 9

Tags: angular

I need to have a feature component like below using ng content or any other way.

```
<app-temp>

   <app-temp-item>

      <app-temp-item-title>

         Title will apply here

      </app-temp-item-title>
   </app-temp-item>
  <app-temp>
```

Then how my temp component should like and currently having angular with version 9.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `app-temp` should have an `ng-content` in its view, and so do `app-temp-item`  and `app-temp-item-title`

Comment: There is not sufficient information to answer this question. What problem are you trying to solve and what have you tried so far?